# No puedo mostrar en un select dinamico selecciona con placeholder laravel

Tags: laravel

No entiendo por que no puedo mostrar selecciona cuando me carga los 
        datos por que al seleccionar este primer select me 
            tiene que cargar todas las gerencias.

En el otro select el 
         problema es que no me lo muestra seleccione y que abajo 
      me tire todos los datos pero si le pongo , `$value = null`,
          al primer seleccione ahi si me funciona el problema es 
     que ya el segundo select me deja de funcionar y no me 
          carga los datos.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('ano', 'Ano:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}

    <div class="col-lg-10">
        {!! Form::select('ano',$anos_consulta,['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'],['id'=>'anos']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es mi otro select donde me mostrara todas las gerencias de ese año que seleccione al principio:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('gerencia', 'Gerencia:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}

    <div class="col-lg-10">
        {{Form::select('gerencia',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'gerencia'])}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Prueba reemplazar `['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'],['id'=>'anos']` por `['placeholder'=>'Selecciona', 'id'=>'anos' ]` .Saludos!

Comment: no me funciona si lo realizo de esta forma ya no me trae los datos

Comment: no me muestra el placeholder entonces

Answer (score 0):

Los atributos deben ir dentro de un mismo array, separados por coma:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('ano', 'Ano:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
     <div class="col-lg-10">
            {!! Form::select('ano',$anos_consulta,['placeholder'=>'Selecciona','id'=>'anos']) !!}
     </div>
</div>
```

Al igual que en este otro caso:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('gerencia', 'Gerencia:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        {{Form::select('gerencia','elArrayconTusDatos',['required'=>'required', 'id'=>'gerencia'])}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Revisa la documentacion https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#drop-down-lists

Comment: Podrías citar una documentación más reciente, al menos de Laravel 5.x.